# Generate tableau trusted ticket doesn't work C#

Tags: c#, http-post, tableau-api

I need to  get a ticket for displaying tableau server  data visualization, but I get -1 instead of ticket always. I tried to use the simple HTML form from this [site](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/testing-trusted-authentication), but anyway I get -1 from my tableau server.

```js
class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   var url = "https://server.com/trusted";
   var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
   var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
   var postData = "username=userName";
   postData += "&target_site=ru&client_ip=76.151.88.1";
   byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);


   request.Method = "POST";
   request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   request.ContentLength = data.Length;

   using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) { stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); }

   var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   var ticket = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
   Console.WriteLine(ticket);
   Console.ReadKey();

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the tableau installation had to be configured.  Look at this link: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_trustIP.htm

Note that you can check on the existing list with this command, and then basically add your machine to that list:

```
tabadmin get wgserver.trusted_hosts
```

Here's a link that talks about possible solutions.  It was handy because it said where the logs were about why it was happening:
http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_trouble_1return.htm

Those logs are here:

```
ProgramData\Tableau\Tableau Server\data\tabsvc\logs\vizqlserver
```